# Android: Numpad always active

Tags: android, numpad

I have an editText (Input type : only numbers) and I already know how show always the keyboard.

I'm currently using this coded in my manifest :

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

But how can I show always**(everytime that the activity starts)** the numpad instead the keyboard ?

Comment: you mean : show editext with input type is numpad ?

Comment: Hello, my code already show this : http://i.imgur.com/hWvGqVU.png and I want to my code show always this : http://i.imgur.com/4ILQMGB.png (Everytime when I start the activity)

Comment: I added this : "Show numpad everytime that the activity starts"

Comment: to show number pad set ``android:inputType="number"`` and ``android:focusable="true"`` for EditText

Comment: @DanhDC I did that but number pad doesn't start automatically when activity starts.

Comment: Are you try set focusable for EditText in Activity ? E.g : after your activity loaded, use ``editText.requestFocus();``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest file, try adding the following to the `<activity>` that you want to show the keyboard when the activity starts:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`

For more options, checkout the [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Danh DC But still doesn't work http://i.imgur.com/kvoHAcE.png .. The numpad still doesn't open.

Comment: @Jorge ok, check my edit answer

Comment: worked, thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

First, add this line to your mainfest

**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible"**

then in xml set the inputtype as

**android:inputType="numberSigned"**

it's work for me , hope you get help

and must set at that view

Comment: and must set at that view <RequestFocus/>